# Does Microsoft SkyDrive have an API?

Tags: api, documentation, storage, onedrive

So with the [recent news that Microsoft Skydrive is going to get bumped to 25GB of storage](http://lifehacker.com/5094242/skydrive-will-upgrade-to-25gb-of-online-storage) per account, does anyone know if SkyDrive has an API?

(And if so, where are the docs?)

Comment: If you want to use SkyDrive as a cloud filesystem then your only option is http://cerulean.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 44, accepted):

SkyDrive (renamed 'OneDrive') has an official API. Details can be found by going to [The OneDrive Developer center](https://dev.onedrive.com/).

You can also find code samples for working with the OneDrive API, along with source code for the SDKs, [on GitHub](https://github.com/OneDrive)

Comment: The only real problem that I can see Dare, is that I can't access ANY file in Skydrive.. only videos, docs, and photos. What if I wanted to let a user of my app store their ebooks on their skydrive and my app could pull them and read on a device.. (if I am incorrect, please correct me as I really would love to find this to be false)

Comment: I manage to build and run this application. There is sing in button. When I click it shows a progress bar and get back to same the page. I does nothing. Could you please suggest me how can I use ur application to upload something to skydrive. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The OneDrive (as SkyDrive is now called) API details can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/onedrive/