# Is it possible to upload something to SkyDrive via .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, upload, onedrive

I've spotted this question:

[Does Microsoft SkyDrive have an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307696/does-microsoft-skydrive-have-an-api)

But not having an API doesn't mean there isn't some way of uploading files to the SkyDrive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break out an HTTP recorder and learn the "API".

HttpFox works. I use HTTPScoop on OSX.