# Programmatic access of SkyDrive

Tags: windows-phone-7, onedrive

Does anyone know how to access SkyDrive programmatically from Windows Phone 7? What API do I use?  I need to upload files from the Phone to SkyDrive and vice versa.

Some code samples would be great. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Microsoft SkyDrive have an API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307696/does-microsoft-skydrive-have-an-api)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now officially integrate parts of SkyDrive with Windows Phone 7 applications.

Details outlined [here](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2011/07/20/developers-learn-how-to-bring-data-from-hotmail-messenger-and-skydrive-to-your-mobile-apps.aspx).

Comment: That stuff assumes you want to create a web browser object and use their javascript API. Which is heavily geared toward tagging photos and fiddling about with social media, with not a lot of support for using Skydrive as a general purpose cloud filesystem.

Comment: Creating a web browser object should really be a problem because a lot of major APIs do that anyway (e.g. Facebook and Twitter). It has nothing to do with the "social" aspect of it.

Comment: I presume you meant "should NOT be a problem". The fact that facebook and twitter do it that way means nothing. They revolve around novelty so their priority is first-to-market and their tendency to quick and dirty solutions gets them hacked regularly. A strong case can be made that the whole "web app" thing is a big ugly hack. Why fire up a whole browser object just to use a scripting language when you can do it directly? Especially on a slow, resource-limited device like a phone?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new Live SDK available from Microsoft which I think can do this. It's also in a very early alpha or beta state: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264574.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a sample based on SkyPad (Developer Preview). Please install the Windows Live Developer preview SDK.

The sample allows to save a file to SkyDrive and dowload it again after saving.

Here the link:
http://blog.mecum.biz/2011/10/windows-phone-7-mango-skydrive-sample/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Live SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/ff621310) to integrate SkyDrive into your Windows Phone applications. Please see [our code samples on GitHub](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK/tree/master/Samples/WindowsPhone).

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements sound pretty much like mine - you just want to use skydrive as a basic cloud filesystem.

I thought Matt's suggestion was an outstanding idea. I obtained the library and set out to port it, but unfortunately the codebase is huge and elaborate and absolutely riddled with the [Serializable] attribute which is not compatible with WP7. It also makes extensive use of several pieces of framework not available in WP7x, including `X509Chain` and `Authorization`.

SkyDriveApi is not even compatible with VS2010 - an attempted conversion produced a big mess so I just tried it out in VS2008.

We could always *write* one. This looks like a fair bit of work so I invite you to collaborate.

---

Well, it's feature complete and working a treat. I'd like to thank people for all the support and assistance I received reverse engineering the protocol using Fiddler, and coding, testing and debugging the prototype into production ready code. I'd like to, but nobody contributed a damn thing. Good luck writing your own.

Comment: That's a horrible attitude to have, programming is hard enough without everyone being cynical and jaded!

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but there's hope that an answer is on the way:

> However, when Mike Torres was asked about features such as better usability, third-party API support, Windows Live Mesh integration, and expandable storage, he acknowledged that these are "top asks" for SkyDrive and said that they are currently "hard at work on SkyDrive as we speak"
>   [Source](http://www.liveside.net/2011/06/08/microsoft-reveals-new-skydrive-features-in-windows-phone-mango-denies-music-streaming/)

Answer (score -1):

[SkyDrive doesn't have an official API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307696/does-microsoft-skydrive-have-an-api) but here are some unofficial ones. I'd start by looking at http://skydriveapiclient.codeplex.com/.
It doesn't claim support for WP7 but you may be able to port it.