# SkyDrive API - accessing documents

Tags: windows-phone-7, onedrive

Not a long time that SkyDrive API is available. The scopes to access are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh243646.aspx). But how to access documents on SkyDrive? What scope to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Microsoft SkyDrive have an API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307696/does-microsoft-skydrive-have-an-api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This blog post](https://blogs.msdn.com/themes/blogs/generic/post.aspx?WeblogApp=b8&y=2011&m=09&d=28&WeblogPostName=extending-quot-windows-8-quot-apps-to-the-cloud-with-skydrive&GroupKeys=) about Windows 8 and Skydrive contains some information about `wl.skydrive` for accessing and `wl.skydrive_update` for uploading data. Also the [SkyPad application](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Skypad-SkyDrive-Sample-8a187bd8) uses these, so it might be worth a try:

```
<live:SignInButton x:Name="signInBtn" Scopes="wl.signin wl.skydrive_update" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
```