# Windows 8 JavaScript App: Is it possible to sync data with SkyDrive?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, onedrive

I have a JavaScript Windows 8 App that stores its data in a JSON file in Local Storage. I would like to sync this JSON file to the SkyDrive to enable users to use the app on different machines. Is this possible and has anyone seen a good resource for implementing this?

Another note, I am building a Win8 Phone companion app, so I would like the data accessible to the phone as well.

I thought about using Roaming Storage, but there is a data limit, and didn't want to limit the app that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243643.aspx

It appears that WL.backgroundDownload and WL.backgroundUpload are what you want

Comment: Also seems to be some info about accessing it on Windows Phone here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108126/skydrive-api-accessing-documents?rq=1
Its for WP7 though, so not sure how up to date that is, presumably on WP8 the API should be the same as Win8 since both are based on WinRT

Comment: Thanks. I have seen this before but couldn't find it. I appreciate your help!!