# Using SkyDrive as a image gallery CMS for a web page

Tags: javascript, php, content-management-system, gallery, onedrive

Using the SkyDrive API I have managed to access a specific SkyDrive account and images in a specific SkyDrive folder.
I am able to pull the requested images to a web gallery and to display them.

My problem is that the SkyDrive login is done manually by typing in the username and password.

I would like to make that login request automatic from the web app/image gallery on the server side.

Is this possible and how?

Soon I will be updating this thread with a working example and some code.

Found a Jomla extension that does what I need. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/galleries/content-photo-gallery/23932

Now how to do this with PHP,WordPress and JavaScript?

Comment: Just look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307696/does-microsoft-skydrive-have-an-api or here: https://www.google.pl/search?q=skydrive+api

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already now that there is a official API. My problem with the API is it creates a manual login for a user. I need it to be automatic from the server side and secure (no username and password in a text file)

Comment: Ok, so please modify your question according to guidelines written here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist - i.e. write what have you done already, what code have you written, what exactly do you need and what kind of problems have you encountered.